# Why are the post history events on this answer incorrect?

Tags: bug, deleted-answers

[This answer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4304/8) (currently deleted, requires 2k+ to view) has a [revision history](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/4304/revisions) and [timeline](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/4304/timeline) that both say I undeleted it Jul 25 at 19:11.

Given that the post is currently deleted, there is no subsequent deletion entry, and I don't recall undeleting the post, what's gone wrong here?

Comment: That's really strange. Seems like maybe a back-end error.